# Is there a way to negate Apache "-R" IP match?

Tags: apache

The [Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html) list `-R` as a unary operator, used in the following example:

```
# Check against the client IP
<If "-R '192.168.1.0/24'">
    Header set matched true
</If>
```

Is there a way to negate it, other than using an `<Else>` directive? Something like this:

```
<If "! -R '127.0.0.1'">
    # Do something only if IP address is not 127.0.0.1
</If>
```

Comment: Shouldn't parenthesis help? Cannot test `"! (-R '127.0.0.1')"` tho.